# Oracle Pivot Multi Table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I am trying to create a Pivot in Oracle. I keep getting the error message

> ORA-00904: "VALUEZ": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 18 Column: 6

Any thoughts?

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT ACC.NBR,CTA.NAMEZ
  FROM ACCS ACC
    JOIN CARS CAR ON CAR.CAR_AAD_ID = ACC.ACC_AAD_ID
    JOIN CTAS CTA ON  CAR_CUS_ID = CTA_CUS_ID
)
PIVOT
(
  MAX(VALUEZ) --comes from table  CTAS (ERROR LINE)
  FOR NAMEZ IN ('1','2','3') --from table CTAS
)
ORDER BY ACC.NBR;
```

As a side note, I would love it if it was possible to turn the ('1','2','3') into a subquery, but it looks like that is not possible from other post i have read. If it was easy it would be (select distinct namez from CTAS)

Comment: shouldn't you qualify where VALUEZ comes from in your PIVOT?

Comment: @kevinsky I tried putting CTAS.VALUEZ or CTA.VALUEZ but in bother cases it got an error "only simple column names allowed here"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns referenced in your PIVOT clause must exist in the row source that is being pivoted.  You select `ACC.NBR,CTA.NAMEZ` from the table; it looks like you need to expand that to `ACC.NBR,CTA.NAMEZ,CTA.VALUEZ`.

You cannot use a subquery to replace the list of pivot values.  I believe the underlying reason for this is that the parser must be able to figure out the columns that the query will produce prior to executing it; so the pivot values must be hardcoded.

What you might be able to do, if it is appropriate to wrap this query up in a procedure or function, is to first execute a query to get the list of pivot values, then build the pivot query string using that information and execute it via dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

> ora-01748: only simple column names allowed here pivot

```
select* from (SELECT TRUNC(I.POST_DATE) DATES FROM INVOICE I 
INNER JOIN INVC_TENDER_V T ON T.INVC_SID=I.INVC_SID)

PIVOT
(COUNT(*)
 FOR T.TENDER_TYPE IN(0,1) )
```